# Verifone E315 integration with other payment gateways

Tags: ios, objective-c, point-of-sale, verifone

I am working on a Mobile POS integration with [Verifone E315](http://global.verifone.com/products/hardware/mobile/verifone-e315/). I am relatively new to this payment processing industry, so i don't know the nuances and how things work. Following are my questions -

1. I would like to know if Verifone E315 is just a card reader or will also take care of payment processing.
2. Also, can we integrate other payment gateways by just using the Verifone E315 as a card reader?
3. Is there any sample code available to read card data with Verifone E315?
4. How does Apple Pay integration works with Verifone E315?

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: I use a global company payment SDK and its windows terminals act as a POS with OMNIKEY card reader and make a contactless payment. I advise you use Verifone SDKs otherwise you will face great difficulties. The app and the POS terminal talks with each other with APDU commands which is very interesting. Also the data is always encrypted / decrypted with different algorithms too. Good luck!

Comment: Apple Pay uses the same exact standard to make contactless card payments as regular, plastic NFC cards. I think contacting Verifone might be the best bet if you're looking for help.

Comment: @ondermerol Thanks for the advise. I still haven't found the Verifone SDK. Hopefully will have to get in touch with a Verifone rep.

Comment: @lxt Thank you, however i am trying to know how things work with Verifone E315 and Apple Pay

Comment: That SDK should not be cost-free. Also mine is Android project, iOS still does not support non-Apple payments.

Answer (score 6):

[payworks](http://www.payworksmobile.com) offers a SDK to do transactions with the E315.

Disclosure: I am a software engineer at payworks

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with all sorts of VeriFone terminals from Tranz/Zon to Omni 3200, to Verix/VerixV and eVo (3740/3750, 3730/510, 570, and 520).  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the E315, but I suspect my answer will apply to it as much as it would to the other platforms (you may want to follow up with a VeriFone rep to make sure--I'm sure he/she would be very happy to discuss it with you if there is a chance you may be buying some more of their hardware).

1. All VeriFone terminals I have ever worked with are just empty hardware--you have to provide all the software in order to make it work.  There are various companies (and I think VeriFone is one of them) that have already developed software for the terminals that will handle credit card processing and/or check processing.  I have never done this, but I've seen them in use in in many stores.  Alternately, you can write your own program which will include all user prompts, all communication to a remote server that will do the actual processing, all the code for printing receipts, etc. (this is what I do).  Obviously, this is a lot more work, but it gives you all the flexibility you could want.
2. That really depends on what you are trying to do, but probably.  We actually do something like this--we read card data on the terminal and then send that card data to a server which in turn connects with one of a variety of other platforms we have integrated with and it all works swimmingly.
3. Again, I'm not familiar with the E315 or its platform, but the SDKs for the other models have all come with lots of documentation including, in some cases, sample code here and there.  Again, contact a VeriFone rep and see what you need to do to get access to their developer's web site, "[DevNet](http://www.verifonedevnet.com)".
4. Sorry--I'm afraid I don't know anything about Apple Pay.

Comment: Thanks for you guidance. Actually i would like to collect as many info as possible before buying Verifone E315 hardwares. Still looking for advise on Apple Pay and E315 connection.

Comment: Oh, sure--I was just saying that if you contact VeriFone and tell them that you might be interested in buying some E315s but you have these questions, they will likely provide you with some guidance because they want to provide you with a solution that will work for you (which in turn will make you want to buy from them).

Comment: Thank you, will try to reach them.